# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS: no appropriate service handler found. How to fix it?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle19c

My system using Oracle.
Sometime It's returns ORA-12519 error.

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

I was check Processs and Sessions with query:

```
select resource_name, current_utilization, max_utilization, limit_value
from v$resource_limit
where resource_name in('processes','sessions');
```

Result:

| RESOURCE_NAME | CURRENT_UTILIZATION | MAX_UTILIZATION | LIMIT_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| processes | 60 | 99 | 300 |
| sessions | 80 | 129 | 505 |

Most of solution is:increase process, So I think problem is not processes low.

Is there any ideal?

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Processes and sessions looks fine.
I think there is something related to network if the issue appears only sometimes.
Try to look at this document in MOS -> [TNS-12519: TNS:no Appropriate Service Handler Found (Doc ID 2966493.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=199130703196989&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2966493.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=9xkswvozx_4)